# Can't download bootstrap in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, twitter-bootstrap-3

Even time I try to download bootstrap in netbeans I get this error and can't figure out why:

Network error occured while processing these requests:  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/bootstrap.zip

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You can download bootstrap from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/) then `unzip` it. you will find 3 folders named `css/fonts/js`. Then copy them to the  `public_html`directory of your site. Next create a new `HTML` file and insert these lines with in the`<head> and </head>`tags `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>` Then you are good to go. for more information refer following links [link1](http://coderdojotullamore.net/NetBeansProjSetup.html) [link2](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)